# Horizontal Swiping between UIViewControllers with Parallax Best Practice

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiscrollview, parallax, custom-transition

I currently face a challenge in which I need to implement a swipe between pages (similar to Yahoo Digest and Yahoo app), also requiring the parallax effect for background images of each `UIViewController`.

I am weighing a few approaches, not sure which is most efficient, quick, and robust to implement, and most importantly, feels REALLY REALLY SMOOTH.

What approach is best practice for implementing this type of feature?

1) `UIScrollView` with paging (like [here](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView))

2) `UIPageViewController` with `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll`

3) iOS 7 custom `UIViewController` interactive transitions.

4) `UICollectionView` with Horizontal scrolling and paging

Considering I need the parallax effect, I need a solution that will play well with this requirement, and not require heavy custom code.

Answer (score 1):

I would say UIScrollView is the cleanest approach. Setting appropriate contentOffset on didScroll you can achieve the parallax effect like in Yahoo weather.

I have also created a sample project using scrollView if you would like to take a look- https://github.com/vin25/SideScrollParallaxEffect-iOS